# How can I make a function that detects a factor in a string and converts it into a float?

Tags: java, processing

In my assignment, my code has to be able to add, subtract, divide and multiply. Most of the work has been done with the help of my teacher, but I cannot figure out, how I should make it able to multiply and divide.

I assume that I need to make a new function that searches for the factors in my string, and then make it create a substring.

I have tried extending the code that was already wirtten by just adding the same function in line 21 and 31, but that did not work.

```
public static int resultat;
  public static String stykket = "3+9-22+35*2";

  public static void main (String[] args)  {

    while (!taltjek(stykket)){
      stykket = findled(stykket);
    }
    if (taltjek(stykket)){

        int tal = StrToInt(stykket);
        stykket = "";
        resultat += tal;
        println(resultat);
      }
    }
    public static String findled(String stykket){

      int tal;
      for(int i = stykket.length() - 1; i > 0;i--){
        if ((stykket.charAt(i) =='+')||(stykket.charAt(i) == '-')||(stykket.charAt(i) == '*')) {
          String strengtal = stykket.substring(i+1, stykket.length());
          tal = StrToInt(strengtal);

          char test = stykket.charAt(i);
          switch(test){
            case '+': resultat += tal;
            break;
            case '-': resultat -= tal;
            break;
            case '*': resultat *= tal;
            break;
          }
          stykket = stykket.substring(0,i);
          i = stykket.length();
        }
      }
      return stykket;
    }

    public static int StrToInt(String subString) {
      int resultat;
      resultat = 0;
      try {
        resultat = Integer.valueOf(subString);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        println("Det der er ikke et tal");
      }
      return resultat;
    }
    public static boolean taltjek (String subString){
      int resultat = 0;
      try {
        resultat = Integer.valueOf(subString);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e)  {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

I expected the output to be 60, but the output is 25.

Comment: are you open to using ScriptEngineManager and ScriptEngine libs which can directly perform arithmetic operation on Strings

Comment: As it is a project for school on the easiest level of programming, and we're limited to using processing, I highly doubt so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code evaluates the string from right to left. Whenever it encounters an operator, it parses the substring right of the operator and applies that operation to the variable "resultat".

`resultat` is not initialized, so it will be `0`. If the first operation is a multiplication, it will remain `0`, because `x*0=0`.

If I print `i` and `resultat` for each iteration of the `for` loop, this is the output (plus my comments)

```
10: 0     // input: 2     resultat = 0
 9: 0     // input: *2    resultat *= 2  =>  0
 8: 0     // input: 5
 7: 0     // input: 35
 6: 35    // input: +35   resultat += 35 => 35
 5: 35    // input: 2
 4: 35    // input: 22
 3: 13    // input: -22   resultat -= 22 => 13
 2: 13    // input: 9
 1: 22    // input: +9    resultat +=  9 => 22
25        // in your main method: resultat += 3 => 25
```

So what your code is really evaluating is `0*2+35-22+9+3`

My suggestion for a fix is:

1. Evaluate from left to right instead
2. Initialize `resultat` with the value before the first operator

I don't know what the requirements for your code are, but IMHO a better way for a expression evaluator is using a recursive approach. The code is simpler (in my opinion) and you can implement operator precedence much easier.

Comment: That is the end goal of the project, but our teacher wanted us to learn it this way first, for some reason. But thanks for the help!